# Using SQL functions in conditionals in Drupal 7 db_select()

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to write a condition into a SQL WHERE clause that forces the column comparison to a variable to be compared in lowercase. However the addExpression function isn't accomplishing this (since that is putting the expression in the field selection, not the where clause.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$category = 'mobile wifi';
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd')
    ->fields('ttd', array('tid'));
$query->innerJoin('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'tv', 'ttd.vid = tv.vid');
$query->addExpression("LOWER(ttd.name) = $category");
$result = $query->condition('machine_name', 'images_cat', '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
```

And this:

```
$category = 'mobile wifi';
$query = db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 'ttd')
    ->fields('ttd', array('tid'));
$query->innerJoin('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'tv', 'ttd.vid = tv.vid');
$result = $query->condition('machine_name', 'images_cat', '=')
    ->condition('LOWER(ttd.name)', $category, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
```

The second one becomes invalid and the first one causes the problem I mentioned above. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

change

```
$query->addExpression("LOWER(ttd.name) = $category");
```

to

```
$query->where('LOWER(ttd.name) = :category', array(':category' => $category));
```

Comment: That works. It didn't even occur to me to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Using `LOWER()` is considered slow in MySQL. It isn't necessary too because `LIKE` in Drupal's Database API (DBTNG) is case insensitive, at least when your MySQL table is configured to use one of the *_ci collations. A standard MySQL installation uses *utf8_general_ci* and so is Drupal.

So you just need to use a LIKE condition:

```
$query->condition('name', $category, 'LIKE');
```

See [Conditional Clauses](http://drupal.org/node/310086) for a comprehensive explaination.

BTW: A DBTNG based database driver is responsible for implementing a case insensitive LIKE. PostgreSQL for instance uses ILIKE instead of LIKE which is handled in *includes/database/pgsql/database.inc*.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use addExpression.

```
// Functions - You can use sql functions using addExpression ($expression, $alias = NULL, $arguments = array()).
$query->addExpression('MIN(o.tid)', 'min_term_id');
```

Resource: [SQL query examples in Drupal 7](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/sql-query-examples-drupal-7)