# How to use the LOWER function in a Drupal query?

Tags: 7, database

I want the query like below:

`select * from tbl where LOWER(name) = $name`

My current query is:

```
$resultArr = db_select('adbanner', 'n')
    ->fields('n')
    ->condition(LOWER('n.blog_title'), $page, '=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

But it doesn't work.

How should I write this type of query?

Comment: There seems to be a typo with the quotes in your condition. Did you mean the following?

    $resultArr = db_select('adbanner', 'n')
        ->fields('n')
        ->condition('LOWER(n.blog_title)', $page, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

Answer (score 3):

You can use `LIKE` instated of `LOWER`.

OR write something

```
$query->where('LOWER(n.blog_title) = :page', array(':page' => $page));
```

Refer [Using SQL functions in conditionals in Drupal 7 db_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15248/using-sql-functions-in-conditionals-in-drupal-7-db-select)

Comment: I believe LIKE is much heavier than LOWER, so the code you showed is preferable.